# Why is this java nested while loop not working?

Tags: java, while-loop

Now I am trying to read txt files and make an array in arraylist with that data. 
I want to read two txt files and compare them, but I can't understand why the inside while loop is not working.

(I used 'count' variable to test inside while loop, but when I printed count variable, it printed only 0.)

(Also I know that try~ catch~ is not good solution for 
NullPointerException error.. but  I couldn't find other solution instead of try~ catch~)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Warehouse {
    static private String[] eachStockElem = new String[5];
    static private String[] eachInputElem = new String[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner str = new Scanner(new File("a.txt"));
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(new File("b.txt"));
        PrintStream st_w = new PrintStream("a.txt");
        PrintStream tx = new PrintStream("c.txt");
        ArrayList<String[]> stockArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String[]> inputArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String[]> txArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String eachTxElem[] = new String[6];
        int tx_id=0;
        int temp_quantity=0;
        int count=0;
        try {
            while (ip.hasNextLine()) {
                eachInputElem = ip.nextLine().split(",");
                inputArrayList.add(eachInputElem);
                while (str.hasNextLine()) { //this while not working!
                    eachStockElem = str.nextLine().split(",");
                    stockArrayList.add(eachStockElem);
                    count++;
                    //do comparing operation
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        str.close();
        ip.close();
        tx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*[...] inside while loop is not working.*" - What does that mean? Does it not compile? Does it throw an `Exception`? Please [edit] your question and add the error message / stack trace. A [MCVE] is required aswell.

Comment: @Turing85 there is no compile error or error message..

Comment: No wonder... `catch(NullPointerException e){ System.out.print(""); }` - change the `System.out.println("");` to `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @Turing85 I changed it, but inside while loop is still not looping. It's hard to explain...Would you mind if you see my whole code?

Comment: Yes, I actually would. Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: It works as intended: when first line of `b.txt` is being processed, you read all lines from `a.txt` and process them. Then, when second line of `b.txt` is read, there are no more lines remain in `a.txt`, and `hasNextLine()` returns `false`. You could reset scanner of `a.txt` after each line of `b.txt` is processed (though that's very inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

By guessing what "this loop does not work" words mean, i am taking the risk to post of what i think is the problem in your case.

**PrintStream in documents:**

> The name of the file to use as the destination of this print stream.
>   If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise,
>   a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and
>   is buffered.

The problem (and the answer, "why it is not working"):

```
Scanner str = new Scanner(new File("a.txt"));
PrintStream st_w = new PrintStream("a.txt"); //Cleans the text file,
// so scanner has no lines to read.
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line,

```
PrintStream st_w = new PrintStream("a.txt");
```

the program is writing the output in the same input file. Change the name of this output file and execute your test case.